# How do I configure Visual Studio 2022 to exclude certain test types by default?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I currently manually add `-trait="Integration"` to the Test Explorer search to make sure I don't run any tests marked as Integration.

[image: example teste explorer search]

How can I make this the default?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to default this search, but I think a good solution to your problem is to make use of a playlist and add all of the tests with the "Integration" trait to the playlist.

1. Right click in the "Tests" portion of the Test Explorer window and select Add to playlist → New playlist.  This will open another text explorer window with your newly created playlist.
2. Click the pencil icon to edit the playlist
3. Filter using the search bar on your trait criteria.
4. Select all the tests you wish to add to the playlist (probably all of them in this case).
5. Save the playlist using the floppy disk icon.

[image: playlist]

You can even pin this playlist window like any other window.  The only downside to this is you have to continue to add new tests to it as you go.  However that should be fairly easy to do via these steps.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like "Group By: Traits" might be what I was looking for. I just tried it with one project, closed VS and opened a new project, and the group by was still set to Traits.

Comment: @ccfoo242 I did also see that, but I thought that would also include all the tests without traits (in there own "no traits" list).  I wasn't sure how narrowed down you wanted your scope to be.  I think playlists offer a nice way for you to organize out your tests at least.

Comment: At the moment we only have tests with either no trait or an Integration trait. The group by gives me two main groups: Integration and "No Traits". So, in the end I grouped by "Trait, Project, Namespace, Class". The playlist would definitely be nice but it would mean everyone on the team would have to update it when they made a change.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the filter in a *vstest.runsettings* file:

```
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <TestCaseFilter>TestCategory!=Integration</TestCaseFilter>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

The `TestCaseFilter` element uses the same syntax as the command line expression used in `dotnet test --filter` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest).